# Hooking basic pages in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook

I have few basic pages in drupal 7, named about, contacts. I tried to make page--about, and style it, but it doesnt work. Any advice on how to force hook basic pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your themes template file you can get template suggestions. This was you can check there isnt anything weird going on. The following will dump out suggestions for templates.

You need to use the following:

```
function YOURTHEME_process_page(&$vars) {
    var_dump($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);
    dsm($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']); //if you have Devel
}
```

You should install the Devel module, this helps alot with theming.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you're using the correct machine name for your content type. Go to content types and copy it from there.

Copy the node.tpl.php file from `root/modules/nodes/` to your theme's templates directory.

Rename the `node.tpl.php` file to `node--MACHINE_NAME.tpl.php`.

Clear the cache in `admin/performance/`. **This is important.**